# EmberJS: force transition to parent route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got two routes: a main route, called `parent`, and a child route of it called `parent.child`. When something happens (let's call it **X**) in `parent.child`, I want to transition to `parent`, but since technically we're already there, Ember does nothing.

```js
// 'parent.child' controller
this.transitionToRoute('parent');
```

So I want to know if there's a way to force this "transition". The reason is that there's code in `parent` that needs to re-run after **X** occurs.

Comment: Where is that code? In the model hook?

Comment: @Lux you mean the code that I want to re-run? Part of it is on the `model` hook of the `parent` route, but I've defined beforeModel and afterModel` as well and I want them to run. In other words, I want it to be like the parent route has been re-entered

Answer (score 3):

You can call [`refresh`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.15/classes/Route/methods/refresh?anchor=refresh)  on your parent route.

Now the simplest way to call an action on your parent route is, well, to define one, and then use `send` on your controller to let the action bubble up.

So your parent route:

```
class ParentRoute extends Route {
  @action
  refreshParent() { // dont name it refresh because of the naming conflict
    this.refresh();
  }
}
```

and your child controller:

```
class ChildController extends Controller {
  @action
  refreshParentRoute() { // again, another name
    // this will first look for a `refreshParent` action on this controller,
    // then the `child` route and last the `parent` route.
    this.send('refreshParent');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get back up our of the child route you can call

```
this.transitionToRoute('parent.index');
```

I'm not sure this solution will fix your problem without seeing your app, for example this probably won't re-run hooks in the parent route, you may need to either move them into `routes/parent/index` or re-design how those hooks work.